# angular 2 input datalist autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

```
const books: Array<{ id: number, title: string }> = [{id: 1, title: "book1"}, {id: 2, title: "book2"}, {id: 3, title: "book3"}, {id: 4, title: "book4"}];

<form [formGroup]="bookForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(bookForm)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>book_id</label>
        <input list="book_list" formControlName="book_id">
        <datalist id="book_list">
            <option *ngFor="let book of books" [ngValue]="book.id">{{book.title}}</option>
        </datalist>{{ bookForm.value | json }}
        <!--display error message if book_id is not valid-->
        <small [hidden]="bookForm.controls.book_id.valid">
          book not selected</small>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am trying to do autocomplete input field using input datalist. Here i want to allow search by book title but want to get book id once one book is selected in angular 2.

1. But i am getting book title instead of book id.
2. How would i map the book title with book id in the input box while the form id in edit mode.

Comment: Add the component class code here

Answer (score 0):

that should be `[value]` not `[ngvalue]`

In component you can extract like below:

```
save(form) {
    console.log(form.book_id.value);
}
```